# SQL - Select last record in subquery, including other conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

We have a portal where certifications are submitted by customers, then assigned to individual trainers and verified by them. I am trying to find out:

1) How many certifications were verified by a particular trainer in last 7 days (SOLVED)

2) How many certifications are currently assigned to the trainer.

This is a part of the database structure:

```
dbo.Attempt  | dbo.AttemptHistory        | dbo.Person      | dbo.Trainer
Id     int   | Id            int         | Id      int     | Id        int
Score  int   | AttemptId     int         | Name    varchar | PersonId  int
             | StatusId      int         | Surname varchar | 
             | ChangeStamp   datetime    |                 |
             | PersonId      int         |                 |
```

When an attempt is received and assigned, 2 AttemptHistory records are created (StatusIds 1 and 5). When it is verified, 3rd AttemptHistory record is created (StatusId 10).

Trainer is represented by PersonId.

To find the number of already verified attempts by a trainer is easy, because the verified StatusId is always the last one in the lifecycle of an Attempt. This is the script to get number of verified Attempts:

```
,(
    SELECT COUNT(Attempt.Id) 
    FROM Attempt

    INNER JOIN AttemptHistory ON AttemptHistory.AttemptId = Attempt.Id

    WHERE AttemptHistory.PersonId = Trainer.PersonId
    AND AttemptHistory.StatusId = 10 
    AND AttemptHistory.ChangeStamp >= Dateadd(Day, -7, getdate())

)                                               
AS AttemptsVerifiedFromTo
```

My question is, how to find out how many attempts are currently assigned to a particular trainer?

When I query the AttemptHistory, I need to find a record that:

1) Belongs to current Attempt (AttemptId)

2) Is assigned to a particular trainer (PersonId)

3) Has the "assigned" status (StatusId)

4) Is the last record (with highest id, or latest changeStamp) belonging to current attempt. In other words - after this "assigned" history record, there is no following record (e.g. with status Verified).

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: This is the whole script I'm using, from which you can see the desired output data structure.

```
SELECT 
     Trainer.Id        AS TrainerId
    ,Trainer.PersonId  AS TrainerPersonId
    ,Person.Name       AS TrainerName
    ,Person.Surname    AS TrainerSurname    
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(Attempt.Id) 
        FROM Attempt

        INNER JOIN AttemptHistory ON AttemptHistory.AttemptId = Attempt.Id

        WHERE AttemptHistory.PersonId = Trainer.PersonId
        AND AttemptHistory.StatusId = 10 
        AND AttemptHistory.ChangeStamp >= Dateadd(Day, -7, getdate())

    )                                               
    AS AttemptsVerifiedFromTo

    ,(  /* THIS IS JUST A TEST I TRIED TO GET THE NUMBER OF ASSIGNED ATTEMPTS */
        SELECT COUNT(Attempt.Id) 
        FROM Attempt

        INNER JOIN AttemptHistory ON AttemptHistory.AttemptId = Attempt.Id

        WHERE AttemptHistory.PersonId = Trainer.PersonId
        AND AttemptHistory.StatusId = 5
        AND Attempt.Reply IS NULL
        AND AttemptHistory.Id = (
            SELECT TOP 1 (AttemptHistory.Id) FROM AttemptHistory
            INNER JOIN Attempt ON AttemptHistory.AttemptId = Attempt.Id
        )
   )                                                
   AS AttemptsAssigned      


FROM Trainer
INNER JOIN Person ON Person.Id = Trainer.PersonId
```

Comment: can you please add your expected output table structure and also add some input data

Comment: @fa06 Added the whole query from which you can see the output table structure.

Comment: actually I mean to add u your expected output in table format, from your query it's very tough to identify which you mean